# Jmeter - Increment value before each sampler request

Tags: java, jmeter, counter, performance-testing

I have test plan in jmeter with few SOAP samplers where I append to request body counter value and I'm looking for way how to increment counter before each sampler request.

With setup below jmeter is peforming requests in this order:

```
First Request - with counter 1
Second Request - with counter 1
First Request - with counter 2
Second Request - with counter 2
```

I would like to achive this behaviour:

```
First Request - with counter 1
Second Request - with counter 2
Third Request - with counter 3
...
N Request - with counter n
```

[image]

**Number of users:**
Number of threads: 1
Ramp-Up Period: 1
Loop Count: 2

**Counter**
Starting value: 1
Increment: 1
Maximum value: 2

How can I do it ? I'm guessing I should introduce Loop Controller somehow ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way:

- In Test Plan, define variable "counter" set to 0
  [image: Counter variable]
- Then add a [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) which is a PreProcessor (so executed BEFORE SAMPLER) component using [__intSum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) function

[image: User Parameters]

It will be executed each time thanks to [scoping rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules).

Answer (score 4):

For auto increment, initialize a variable let say "id" with 0 in the user defined variable then use ${__intSum(${id},1,id)} for auto increment as shown below:-

[image]
[image]